# Git: push committed changes to the current branch only

Tags: git

I'm working on a branch of my master repository:

```
$ git branch
* as-testsuite
  master
```

I've added unstaged changes and committed them. Now I'd like to push them on the current branch "as-testsuite". Just on that branch, **not** in my master branch.

```
$ git push
fatal: The current branch as-testsuite has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use
```

I do have have added an upstream repository for push (as I can see from git remote -v). Pardon the silly question, why do I have to provide additional options if I want to use the current branch?
Should I use?

```
$ git push origin as-testsuite
```

Thanks a lot